# In what order do the washers go on smooth post cantilever brakes

Tags: brakes, cantilever, concave

I have a Specialized Rockhopper that is missing the brakes. It has cantilever brakes smooth post. I have the parts but don't know what order the washers go in. Does the concave part go against the brake pad and nut? Or against the brake arm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Orders of the washers on threaded-stud brake shoes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45147/orders-of-the-washers-on-threaded-stud-brake-shoes)

Comment: @DavidW I've flagged it as a duplicate of that question as well, but I've retracted my flag (or I intended to do so by removing the auto-comment). The duplicate seems about brakes with a threaded stud, while the question asker focusses on brakes with a smooth post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Park Tool has an [instruction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_tDym0G6zo) on mounting/adjusting cantilever smooth post brakes.
At [6:26 into the video](https://youtu.be/G_tDym0G6zo?t=386) they show one brake arm with the pads installed, with the washers clearly visible:

[image]

The concave washers seem to go agains the brake arm.